# Compose a Vim quine!

Tags: quine, vim

Goal:

Create and save file in Vim containing at least 25 ASCII characters. The *exact keystrokes* used during the creation and saving of this file must also produce identical contents in Windows Notepad (without having to save in Notepad).

Rules:

- For the purposes of this challenge, Vim begins open in command mode.
- The mouse is **not** allowed.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> ***is*** allowed. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, or any other modifier keys are ***not*** allowed.
- Your solution must work with the **default** "terminal" (non-GUI) Vim shipped with either Ubuntu 11.04 or OS X 10.6.7 (one of the two). Assume this Vim's `.vimrc` contains only `set nocompatible` (with no line break after it), which is itself located at `~/.vimrc`. Pretend your operating system was *just* installed before opening Vim.
- You must not open any *pre-existing* files except for your `.vimrc`. Any files you create while solving this puzzle may be saved and re-opened as many times as necessary.
- Vim cannot be closed!

*Disclosure, and  a possible reason to close:* I do not have a solution.

Comment: -1 for mentioning Notepad.

Comment: user unknown: That's a quite stupid reason for downvoting, actually.

Comment: @Joey Don't try to find logic in a fanboy's reasoning.

Comment: You should add an objective winning criterium, like amount of votes or character/byte count.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The edited sequence (the first version was mangled).

<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>  <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
<kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Should do the trick, if I'm counting my keystrokes correctly. No wait, is the escape key allowed?

Comment: All I get is a file containing ":wq" followed by a couple newlines.

Comment: Oops, I've mangled the sequence. Will fix in a moment.

Comment: Hmmm, what about the `Vim cannot be closed` requirement? I suppose the solution is simple enough: remove the two `q`'s and one of the backspaces.

Comment: Also, by <kbd>A</kbd>, do you mean <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> ?

Comment: @asoundmove ah yes, missed that part. Removing both "q"s and a backspace should fix it. @Joey Adams; I mean Shift+A indeed, but this notation takes too much space, enough is enough!

Comment: Awesome. Well done. :)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Produces "hello, world" in both.

Answer (score 1):

34 keystrokes. Produces twenty-two A's followed by :x and a new line.

<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>  <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>